# Is the Facebook share custom description trackable?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Is it possible to get the description that visitor used to share a page on Facebook after clicking the page's share button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to see what description the user entered when sharing your page or other content. If the share is public then you'll be able to retrieve the share text if you know the user's facebook ID, but it will require Facebook API calls.